# How to remove all rows from a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame from which I want to delete all rows while keeping original structure (columns).

```r
ddf <- data.frame(
  vint1 = c(9L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 7L),
  vint2 = c(10L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 12L),
  vfac1 = factor(c("1", "3", "2", "2", "3")),
  vfac2 = factor(c("3", "4", "2", "4", "2"))
)
ddf
#>   vint1 vint2 vfac1 vfac2
#> 1     9    10     1     3
#> 2     9     6     3     4
#> 3     6     2     2     2
#> 4    10     6     2     4
#> 5     7    12     3     2
```

I tried:

```
ddf = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(ddf) ddf[i,] = NULL
```

but they do not work. Thanks for your help on this basic question.

Comment: Instead of `0`, might be better to use `df[NULL, ]`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you really want to delete all rows:

```
> ddf <- ddf[0,]
> ddf
[1] vint1 vint2 vfac1 vfac2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If you mean by keeping the structure using placeholders:

```
> ddf[,]=matrix(ncol=ncol(ddf), rep(NA, prod(dim(ddf))))
> ddf
  vint1 vint2 vfac1 vfac2
1    NA    NA    NA    NA
2    NA    NA    NA    NA
3    NA    NA    NA    NA
4    NA    NA    NA    NA
5    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Why the zero? I think `ddf <- ddf[c(), ]` makes more sense.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - wouldn't `df[NULL,]` be most appropriate, logically?

Comment: Well, if you know what indexing with `NULL` means. Similarly to indexing with zero. They are both documented, so they are fine solutions. But I think `c()` is just more intuitive, you select zero rows. To be sure about `NULL` and zero I had to check the manual..... But maybe it's just me and everybody else knows what indexing with `NULL` means.

Comment: Of `c()`, `NULL` and `0`, I'll choose the one that's easiest to type.

Comment: Perhaps this is better than your second suggestion: `ddf[which(!is.na(ddf), arr.ind = TRUE)] <- NA`. Whereas your second suggestion just creates a single type of `NA`, my suggestion retains things like the original factor levels and assigns the correct `NA` type to each column.

Comment: All three methods require your data.frame to have more than one column... the more you know